# Neo4jrb: Enumerator for model_class: false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j.rb

When specifying a `model_class` of `false`, it's expected that the connection from this node to another could be any other class of node.

Is there a reciprocal enumerator so that we can call something like:

`ActiveNodes.all`

when giving the user a selection of nodes to choose from?

Note (and warning to anyone thinking about this): Looking for all nodes would not scale *at all*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got a good use case we would certainly consider it something to make this easier.  The problem is, though, there would be no associations to browse at that point because there's no model involved.  You might just want to use the `Query` API at that point:

```
Neo4j::Session.current.query.match(:n).where(n: {foo: 'bar'}).etc...
```

The documentation for all of the methods is here:

http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.io/en/7.0.x/QueryClauseMethods.html

**EDIT:**

Editing the post based on your comment because there isn't enough room in a comment ;)

Your example is that you have a `Product` and you would like to be able to find other models which are linked with the same relationship type.  Here's what I might do:

```
class Product
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode

  has_one :out, :file, type: :RELATED_FILE, model_class: %i(ProductImage ProductVideo ProductPDF)

 # optionally
 has_one :out, :image_file, type: :RELATED_FILE, model_class: :ProductImage
 has_one :out, :video_file, type: :RELATED_FILE, model_class: :ProductVideo
 has_one :out, :pdf_file, type: :RELATED_FILE, model_class: :ProductPDF
end
```

These could also be changed to `has_many` and work just the same if there's the possibility of having more than one associated.

Then you should be able to generate a select tag in the view which has all of the options and which will pass the ID(s) down to the controller via params and then you could just do:

```
Product.create(name: 'or whatever props you have', file_id: params[:file_id])
```

If the association is `has_many` you could instead do `file_ids: params[:file_ids]`.

You might also consider inheriting those associated models from a single class like this:

```
class File
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
end

class ProductImage < File
  # No need to `include Neo4j::ActiveNode`
end
```

Then you could do the array of models like I suggested above, or you could simply do:

```
class Product
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode

  has_one :out, :file, type: :RELATED_FILE
end
```

`model_class: :File` is assumed based on the association's name.  If you had `has_many` then your association name would be `:files` and it will still assume `model_class: :File`.

Just be aware that if you do this, nodes for your associated models (`ProductImage`, `ProductVideo`, and `ProductPDF`) would all also have the `File` label because of the inheritance.

As a separate modeling suggestion, I would probably just have an `Image` model (for example) rather than `ProductImage` so that the model could be potentially re-used.

Comment: I can't imagine a general use-case where search for all nodes would be beneficial. The biggest general use-case along this line is the same relationship type to different labels. Maybe there's a better way to handle that?

Comment: Do you mean like on an association?

Comment: Here's an example: I have a Product that can link to any type of file. for Rails sanity, each file group has it's own class: `ProductImage`, `ProductVideo`, `ProductPDF`, and so-on. they all have the same relationship type: `[:RELATED_FILE]`, and I want the user to be able to choose any type of file in a single field. In Cypher, this is simple. In Neo4j; is there a way?

Comment: Looking at your edit; I was afraid of that.
I saw this as a possible solution, but it adds a lot of complication that the Neo4j graph just doesn't have.
I'm going to accept this because it looks like the only solution that fits in Neo4jrb.

P.s. the `%i(ProductImage ProductVideo ProductPDF)` is a handy shortcut I wasn't aware of, that will come in handy.

Comment: Thank you for putting in the time to write a comprehensive answer.